# Character with indexes on every corner

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I want to write characters in latex with indexes in every corner. For example to write a transformationmatrix from the basis B to the basis B' i need smth like this:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basiswechsel_%28Vektorraum%29#/media/File:Change_of_basis_square2.svg

how can i do that with latex?

Comment: Duplicate? [Commutative Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783)

Comment: nonono :D i was not aiming for the diagram, but for the character "T" with the two B's on the left side

Comment: Just put the superscript and subscript one after the other: `$T_{B\prime}^{B}$`  See also [Order of subscript and superscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62956).

Comment: ok and how can i get a subscribt on the left side of a character?
EDIT: ok, i got it: _{B}T_{B\prime} gets me what i wanted. Thank you though!

Comment: A little searching on the site goes a long way. [Left and right subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542)

Comment: yea, well after all i solved it on my own. but in the first place i was unable to search for it since i didn't know those expressions "subscript" and "superscript"

Comment: Fair enough. :) Assuming you've been reading intro guides in German, the [LaTeX Short Intro](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/) document has been translated into many languages, so looking at the English version in conjunction with the German version might be a good way of learning some of the corresponding English terms.  Welcome to the site, though, and I didn't mean to sound unfriendly.